# Using 'drive' google drive cli

Tags: google-drive, golang

I installed the (quasi?) official gdrive linux cli based on instructions from [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/196635/an-official-google-drive-for-linux-is-here-sort-of-maybe-this-is-all-well-ever-get/).

This failed with the following message:
  $ go get github.com/odeke-em/drive/cmd/drive
    go tool: no such tool "8g"

tth's answer below explains that this is due to the Go apt repo being out of date and explains how to do the install. Note that:
- the "drive" github has also changed since the howtogeek instructions were written.
- GOROOT and GOPATH environmental variables need to be set*
- both of these folders should have ./bin subfolders &
- the PATH needs to point to both of these.

*I did this by appending these lines to ~/.bashrc:

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=/home/bir/.go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin:$GOROOT/bin
```

(I think this is a better place to do it than ~/.profile because it (also?) affects [non-login shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell). But I only just learned about the distinction so could be wrong :) )

Answer (score 0):

I came across your post while having similar problems, here's what I did.

Firstly the apt package golang is no longer maintained, see Rakyll's comment [here](https://github.com/rakyll/drive/issues/8#issuecomment-61707616)

Remove the old version of golang.

`$ sudo apt-get purge golang*`

You will see a message about dirs that couldn't be removed as they aren't empty, remove these manually.

`$ sudo rm -rf $PathToDir`

See [this page](http://golang.org/doc/install) for download and installation of the most up to date Go package. I also downloaded the source package and extracted to /usr/share although I'm not sure if this is necessary. Further down the page is a neat little test to check Go is working.

Once you have the latest version of Go, you'll need to set your GOPATH variable. Your GOPATH can be wherever you like, mine is $HOME/go. You'll need to manually create the dir.

`$ mkdir go`

`$ export GOPATH=$HOME/go`

This will only set the GOPATH for the current terminal session, I haven't worked out how to set this permanently but you should now be able to run

`$ go get github.com/odeke-em/drive/cmd/drive`

It asked for my GitHub credentials, I didn't have an account so I created one - It's free.

In order to be able to execute Go and Drive, I added their locations to my PATH variable in $HOME/.profile

`$ nano .profile`

And at the bottom add

`PATH="$PATH:/$HOME/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin"`

Apologies for any sense of egg sucking teaching, I'm normally asking for ideas!

Tom

** For completeness I should add that I'm running Debian **

Comment: Well done figuring it out; I got messed up by the non-working apt package + failing to realise the  PATH doesn't just point to GOROOT & GOPATH, but to their /bin subdirectory (at least one of which didn't exist when I was doing this earlier due to the apt go problem).